# About asymptotic expansion of parabolic cylinder functions

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, reference-works

Let's have the parabolic cylinder function $U(a,z)$. I'm interested in its asymptotics for large argument $z$. [Here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/12.9) I've found it, but I'm a bit confuzed now because of expressions $(12.9.1)$ and $(12.9.3)$. The first one is valid if 
$$
\tag 1 |\text{arg}(z)| < \frac{3\pi}{4},
$$ 
while the second one is valid for
$$
\tag 2 \frac{\pi}{4} < |\text{arg}(z)| < \frac{5 \pi}{4}
$$
The second one expression is, however, radically different from the first one, while conditions $(2)$ and $(1)$ are particularly overlapped. For my case, the phase is $ \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3 \pi}{4}$. So is the formula $(12.9.1)$ correct for my case? Maybe, there must be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ instead of $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ in $(1)$?

Comment: The second does not apply because $\pi/4 \not \gt \pi/4$ or do I miss something obvious?

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in correctness of $(1)$.

Comment: Although it might not be convincing because it has the same author, the following article by Temme and Vidunas, Parabolic cylinder functions: examples of error bounds for asymptotic expansions, Analysis and Applications, 1, p.265–288,
available as http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/10701/10701A.pdf gives some hints about the relation of the two expansions.